# vb.net から MySQL への接続ができません

Tags: mysql, vb.net

サーバー: Ubuntu に MySQL
クライアント: Windows 10

クライアントより　vb.net formアプリ（以下、アプリ）で、サーバーのDBに接続したいのですが、
接続できません。

サーバーとクライアントの接続を確立するために、アプリの＜サーバーエクスプローラー＞より
＜データ接続＞→＜接続の追加＞にて
データソース : MySQL Database (MySQL Data Provider)
Server name : 192.168.++.+++
User name   : +++++
Password    : +++++

(Server name　はサーバーのアドレス
User name　はサーバーにログインする時のユーザー
Password　は上記ユーザーのパスワード)

で＜テスト接続＞すると次のエラーで拒否されます。

```
”Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
 １つ以上のエラーが発生しました。
 対象のコンピュータによって拒否され、接続できませんでした。
 192.168.++.+++:3306”
```

以前は、一度同様のアプリを作成したのですが、その時は、
＜接続の追加＞より新たな接続が登録したら、
アプリから SQL を発行できたとおもうのですが、
なぜか今回は上手くいきません。

クライアントとサーバーの通信はホストベース認証によって行っています。

MySQL の操作は、クライアント側より　workbench　にて出来ているので、
（テーブルの定義やファンクション・プロシジャーの作成等はクライアント側より
問題なく出来ています。）
接続の環境の問題ではないように思われます。

＜接続の追加＞をせずに、アプリを動かしてみると、connection の open時に以下のメッセージが表示されて落ちます。

```
MySqlConnector.MySqlException: 'Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.'
```

解決のヒントでも頂ければ幸いです。

Comment: クライアントから workbench で接続するときは、上記 user でログインした後、MySQL で作成したユーザーでdbに接続しています。

Comment: 「接続の追加」で使用しているのは Ubuntu へのログイン情報という事でしょうか？ここで MySQL のユーザー名とパスワードを使用する必要がある気がします。